# How to parse e_magic and e_lfanew so as to understand whether it is a PE file in Python with Pefile?

Tags: python, portable-executable

I have downloaded a file via this link:
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe?ts=gAAAAABi5vYXXchWwmfZlmf0s7uR-VDPFjt_6mO12v4iHHvw9JUle2xu-hqCS3AY_VB0FSmVzo70uhQU4RD8_7ud5dHWalLiYg%3D%3D&use_mirror=altushost-swe&r=

I want to check whether it is a PE file. Slicing strings and retrieving the end part of the link as an EXE file won't cut it since the file theoretically could be named as an EXE, but in all reality not be one, so I've tried using Pefile.

[image: This is what I get when using Pefile]

I won't lie, I have no idea what I am looking at. I Understand the part that I have to look at "e_magic" and "e_flaw", but other than that I am lost. Is there a way for me to retrieve those two specific values and parse them into a string or something of the sort to determine whether it is PE or not? Sorry, but I've been scrolling on the net for hours and there are close to no examples of this.

Here is the code:

```
pe = pefile.PE(r"Downloads/mingw-get-setup.exe")
pe.print_info()
```

Obviously nothing special. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For a quick-and-dirty solution, I just tried to use `pefile` to parse a random python script, and got the following error:

> `pefile.PEFormatError: 'DOS Header magic not found.'`

Stack trace:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[...]/pefile.py", line 2777, in __init__
    self.__parse__(name, data, fast_load)
  File "[...]/pefile.py", line 2891, in __parse__
    raise PEFormatError("DOS Header magic not found.")
```

You can dig into the code to find out what checks does this library do, but it looks like that it actually checks if the file is a PE file.

Another quick way is to simply use the POSIX-builtin `file` command: `file my_exe.exe`.

If you want to check manually, I found this page: [Static Detection of Portable Executable Files](https://winternl.com/static-detection-of-portable-executable-files/)
 by searching for "identify portable executable". It's quite a detailed page.

Comment: Edit: So basically, if a DOS Header is not found, it means that the file is not a windows PE?

Comment: @Matas.Mik quite possibly, but to be sure, you can check the code yourself

Comment: I downloaded like 50 files from Sourceforge. When I run to delete files that do not have a header, only exe are left, so I assume that is the case? Honestly, I can't really check much of the code, hence why I asked this question, this whole hex thing is confusing :|